# How to generate OpenApi client with openapi-generator-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a [OpenAPI](https://www.openapis.org/) (version 2) specification file and I want to generate a client with [`openapi-generator-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin). Unfortunately, it doesn't generate all neccessary classes, therefore the generated sources can not be compiled.

**POM**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-client</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/openapi/api.json</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                <configOptions>
                    <sourceFolder>/</sourceFolder>
                </configOptions>
                <library>resttemplate</library>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**OpenAPI**

```json
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "title": "Test"
    },
    "host": "localhost:8080",
    "basePath": "/",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "test-controller"
        }
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/test": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "test-controller"
                ],
                "operationId": "test",
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Generated sources**

In the directory `target/generated-sources/openapi` only the file `TestControllerApi` of the sub package `api` is generated. The class `org.openapitools.client.ApiClient` is not generated.

[image: directory]

**Logs**

```
[INFO] --- openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.1.0:generate (generate-client) @ test ---
[INFO] Generating with dryRun=false
[INFO] No .openapi-generator-ignore file found.
[INFO] OpenAPI Generator: java (client)
[INFO] Generator 'java' is considered stable.
[INFO] Environment variable JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE not defined so the Java code may not be properly formatted. To define it, try 'export JAVA_POST_PROCESS_FILE="/usr/local/bin/clang-format -i"' (Linux/Mac)
[INFO] NOTE: To enable file post-processing, 'enablePostProcessFile' must be set to `true` (--enable-post-process-file for CLI).
[INFO] Processing operation test
[WARNING] 'scheme' not defined in the spec (2.0). Default to [http] for server URL [http://localhost:8080/]
[WARNING] 'scheme' not defined in the spec (2.0). Default to [http] for server URL [http://localhost:8080/]
[ERROR] Missing required field info version. Default appVersion set to 1.0.0
[ERROR] Missing required field info version. Default version set to 1.0.0
[WARNING] 'scheme' not defined in the spec (2.0). Default to [http] for server URL [http://localhost:8080/]
[INFO] writing file D:\tmp\workspace\test\target\generated-sources\openapi\org\openapitools\client\api\TestControllerApi.java
[INFO] Skipped D:\tmp\workspace\test\target\generated-sources\openapi\src\test\java\org\openapitools\client\api\TestControllerApiTest.java (Skipped by apiTests options supplied by user.)
[INFO] Skipped D:\tmp\workspace\test\target\generated-sources\openapi\docs\TestControllerApi.md (Skipped by apiDocs options supplied by user.)
[WARNING] 'scheme' not defined in the spec (2.0). Default to [http] for server URL [http://localhost:8080/]
[INFO] Skipping generation of supporting files.
[...]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 51 source files to D:\tmp\workspace\test\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /D:/tmp/workspace/test/target/generated-sources/openapi/org/openapitools/client/api/TestControllerApi.java:[3,31] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ApiClient
  location: package org.openapitools.client
```

**Research**

I found a related issue: [10048](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/10048), but it contains no solution.

**Question**

How to configure the plugin to generate all neccessary classes?

Comment: Not that this solves your issue but why do you have `.../src/main/openapi/api.json`? I'd expect a JSON in `.../src/main/resources/...`. And that's also what's declared at `<inputSec>`in [the usage example on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin).

Comment: @GeroldBroser It is not neccessary to package the JSON file. With this path the JSON is not in the JAR file.

Comment: [`jar:jar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html#Optional_Parametersl) has an `<excludes>` property.

Comment: @GeroldBroser Sure, but it would be an additional configuration in POM.xml. It is easier to use another path.

Comment: The declarative nature of a POM describes how your project looks like. "Hiding" information in a `path` in a `<configuration>` `<...property...>` of a `<build>` `<plugin>`, well, hides the information (at first sight) that your project's artifact doesn't contain this JSON. This might sound puristic but there's also the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and [Convention Over Configuration](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/installation-sect-conventionConfiguration.html).

Comment: @GeroldBroser Sure I tried it, it is the default. I switched off the flag, because I don't need these files. I don't work with Gradle, I use Maven. I don't need Shell scripts, I work with Windows. `ApiClient` isn't a supporting class, it seems like a mandatory class.

Answer (score 3):

`generateSupportingFiles` should be `true`.

Comment: I switch off this flag, because I don't want to generate files like: `build.gradle`, `git_push.sh`, ...  It is not neccessary and it is also in the wrong place under generated sources. That makes only sense if I generate a whole project, but I want to include the client into an existing project.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are missing in you configuration

```
<supportingFilesToGenerate>
ApiCallback.java,ApiClient.java,ApiException.java,ApiResponse.java,Configuration.java,Pair.java,ProgressRequestBody.java,ProgressResponseBody.java,StringUtil.java,ApiKeyAuth.java,Authentication.java,HttpBasicAuth.java,JSON.java,OAuth.java,EncodingUtils.java
</supportingFilesToGenerate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `java` generator does not generate an API class for all the endpoints, instead, it generates an interface for each and every endpoint. Try checking the generated classes again, you may find `GetBooksApi` or `FindCarApi` instead of `ApiClient`. Just tested and it does not, indeed. Check the api.package.